# htaccess - redirect with condition not working on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

I have this redirect in htaccess

I want to redirect

```
http://localhost/www/foo/bar.php?city=new_york&data=4156
```

to

```
http://localhost/www/foo/new_york/?&data=4156
```

I have create this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  bar\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city\=([^&]+)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/bar.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/%1/?%2 [L,R=301]
```

But this is not working on localhost. The URL stays the same, old one. I have tested the rules with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and they seem to be working as expected. So is this just a localhost thing or is the htaccess wrong?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)city=([^&]+)(?:&|$)`

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Is it inside the `/foo/` directory?

Comment: @anubhava yes, it is in /foo/ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in `foo/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city=([^&]+)&(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^bar\.php$ /foo/%1/?%2 [L,R=301]
```

Note that this will redirect to `http://localhost/www/foo/new_york/?data=4156` as there is no point of having a `&` right after `?` in URL.